# CSS - line-height:0 ignored in XHTML strict in Firefox

Tags: firefox, xhtml, css, strict

I'm using `:first-line { line-height:0px; }` to hide the empty first line in a block statement
curiously if I define doctype in XHTML strict Firefox ignores this statement and prints the empty line (seeable through the border)

I validated my quellcode and used Firefox' webdeveloper to check, if there is anything wrong, but they told no error

the (stripped) example quellcode is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>T</title>

<style type="text/css"><!--
.v { white-space:pre; display:inline-block; border:1px solid black; }
.v:first-line { line-height:0px; }
--></style>

</head><body>

<p class="v">
  Foo
  Bar
</p>

</body></html>
```

Is there anything wrong with my code and other browsers (I've tested Opera,Gnome,Safari) just ignore the strict, or is Firefox buggy abiding strict?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's really a bug …

I guess the internals of the `:first-line` selector fail to recognize an empty line with just a newline character in it, but I'm not sure if this is wanted or not. There is nothing inside the W3C Recommendations to prove this behaviour as wrong or right:

**CSS 2.1 Specifications:**

> **5.12.1 The :first-line pseudo-element**
>   The :first-line pseudo-element applies special styles to the contents
>   of the first formatted line of a paragraph.

--

> **16.6 White space: the 'white-space' property**
>   'white-space'
>   ...
>    *pre* This value prevents user agents from collapsing sequences of white space. Lines are only broken at preserved newline characters.

If you're generating your HTML code dynamically just try to eliminate the empty line before outputting it. That's the only advice I can give at the moment.

Comment: the recognization succeeds, because when I define `line-height:40px` I can see a larger empty space. however the empty line results because of the linebreak between `<p>` and `Foo` and I don't want to remove that linebreak (it'd be ugly). thanks anyway

Comment: @Hachi Okay, didn't checked that – shame on me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using two colons instead of one. [From Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3a%3afirst-line):

> The :first-line CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first line of
>   a element. However, **the selector :first-line does not match any real**
>   HTML element.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean with colons? the p-paragraph contains text, I'm not responsible for. I just want to hide the empty line inserted because of the linebreak between `<p>` and `Foo`